# Chrome + WooCommerce + WordPress causing timeouts when editing a post/page/etc, to the point it brings the site down

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

Weird one this.

So, Wordpress build with WooCommerce, a new build for an existing client with previous order history, products, pages, etc.

Every day, 3/4 times in Chrome only (tried on a few different machines between 3 of us) after updating a Page/Post/Whatever in WP Admin, the site hangs, you know with the loading spinner always at it, and it doesn't seem to time out to a 500 like you'd expect, just keeps spinning.

Now, after a minute or two, anyone else visiting the site also has a site that doesn't respond and just keeps trying to load.

The weird bit, when I quit Chrome, anyone else / or the other browsers I have open spring into action, and the site is back to normal.

I've tried this in Firefox and Safari too, and can only seem to trigger this issue in Chrome.

I've also tried the following:
- Uninstalling all other plugins
- Re-uploading fresh WP files
- Re-installing WooCommerce with fresh files

The problem only seems to happen with WooCommerce is activated, which seems bizarre enough. No error messages or anything from PHP.

It's like Chrome in WP admin is doing its own DoS attack! I presume Chrome is somehow just upsetting Apache/PHP and firing in too may requests, or something... No idea.

Any ideas?

Comment: This happened once on a client's website. He had 2 lines after the closing`?>` tag in the functions.php file. That means unexpected output was delivered to the browser and somehow the hole thing hung there.

Comment: Not that sadly, never have a closing ?> in those files for that reason, and we de-activated the theme and tried twentytwenty that presented the same issue, so that rules out anything in the theme.